# Advanced control Auth::Check

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

if the columns in the table value of admin, I want to show the admin page, not water to another page

```
$type = array('type' =>'Admin');
if (Auth::check($type))
{
    return view('admin.index');
}
Auth::logout();
return View::make('admin.auth.login');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change your **RedirectIfAuthenticated.php** file. It's stored in `/app/Http/Middleware`. In the handle function you can check if the user has a specific value in the database and redirect to another page accordingly.

Comment: I'm not talking about orientation, I want to add to check the condition author

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem

```
 public function showLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            if (auth()->user()->type!='Admin')
            {
               return view('helperpage.admin-yetki');
            }
            else
            {
                return view('admin.index');
            }

        }

        return View::make('admin.auth.login');
    }
```

Comment: @Yado's answer is definitely the better approach. You are replicating functionality that is already handled by the built-in middleware.